# Retrieving All instances of an 3rd level XML field from an XML column

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012

I have an XML data field in one of my tables that essentially looks like this:

```
<App xmlns='http://Namespace1'>
    <Package xmlns='http://Namespace2'>
        <Item>
            <ItemDetails xmlns='http://Namespace3'>
                <ItemName>ItemNameValue</ItemName>
            </ItemDetails>
            other_item_stuff
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemDetails>
                    <ItemName>ItemNameValue</ItemName>
            </ItemDetails>
        </Item>
        ...
    </Package>
</App>
```

I need to get all of the ItemNameValues from the XML.

I have tried to adapt many examples found on the web to my purpose, but have failed miserably. The best I seem to be able to do is get one ItemName per Package.
I think that CROSS APPLY is where I need to go, but the syntax to retrieve all the itemdetail.itemname eludes me.

This is my latest failure (returns nothing):

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
'http://Namespace1' AS xsd,
'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi,
'http://Namespace2' AS ns1,
'http://Namespace3' AS ns2)            
Items.d.value('(ns2:ItemDetails/ItemName/text())[1]','varchar(200)') as 
ItemName
FROM MyTable
CROSS APPLY XMLDataColumn.nodes('/xsd:App/ns1:Package/ns1:Item') Items(d)
```

I hope to get several records from each XML field, but can only ever get the first element.

Comment: Your query suggests you have namespaces, but your xml contains none. Is that the problem?

Comment: Also, a node being called "<App Namespace1>" isn't valid. We need **valid** sample data here. If we *correct* your xml/query by removing all references to namespaces, your query works fine. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4c70127428c92c9e59058614d6ec914a)

Comment: Namespace1 et al are just  placeholders to illustrate that there are namespaces involved. I was typing this on my phone and trying to be brief.  Data is proprietary, so I can't provide the data I am using. 
I tried removing namespace references in my query, but still get no records.

I am hoping to get an indication of how my xPath syntaxes (or the actual sql) might be failing me.

Comment: The problem with that, however, is that it means we can't replicate your problem. As i said, your code, with what we have, *appears* to work fine.

Comment: I have edited the post a bit to make the namespace thing clearer.

Comment: As it turns out, most of my queries work if I strip the namespaces and prefixes out of the xml column.
So I guess my real question is how do I ignore all those prefixes and namespaces.

Comment: Without **valid** xml, there's little we can do to help you here, James. That current example isn't valid either. if you try and put it in an `xml` column you'll get multiple errors. If you can't provide data that replicates the issue then there's nothing we can do here to help you fix an issue that appears to not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem in this issue is the XML itself:

```
<App xmlns="http://Namespace1">
  <Package xmlns="http://Namespace2">
    <Item>
      <ItemDetails xmlns="http://Namespace3">
        <ItemName>ItemNameValue</ItemName>
      </ItemDetails>
            other_item_stuff
        </Item>
    <Item>
      <ItemDetails>
        <ItemName>ItemNameValue</ItemName>
      </ItemDetails>
    </Item>
        ...
    </Package>
</App>
```

Two major Problems:

- The namespaces are all declared as *default namespaces* (they do not include a prefix). All nodes *within a node* share the same default namespace, if there is nothing else stated explicitly.
- The first `<ItemDetails>` is living within namespace `http://Namespace3`, while the second `<ItemDetails>` is living within namespace `http://Namespace2` (inherited from `<Package>`)

That means: If you can - by any chance - change the construction of the XML, try to do this first.

If you have to deal with this, you can try this clean, but clumsy approach.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
'http://Namespace1' AS ns1,
'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi,
'http://Namespace2' AS ns2,
'http://Namespace3' AS ns3)    
SELECT COALESCE(Items.d.value('(ns2:ItemDetails/ns2:ItemName/text())[1]','varchar(200)')
               ,Items.d.value('(ns3:ItemDetails/ns3:ItemName/text())[1]','varchar(200)')) AS ItemName
FROM @xml.nodes('/ns1:App/ns2:Package/ns2:Item') Items(d);
```

Another approach is to use a *namespace wildcard*, but be aware of ambigous names...

```
SELECT Items.d.value('(*:ItemDetails/*:ItemName/text())[1]','varchar(200)') AS ItemName
FROM @xml.nodes('/*:App/*:Package/*:Item') Items(d)
```